# Windows 7 keeping updating and does not shutdown

Tags: windows-7, windows, updates, windows-update

It's been four days now, every time that I try to shutdown my computer, Windows tries to install updates, no problem with that, but the "updating" screen remains for more than 8 hours. 
This started to happen after I installed Visual Web Developer 2010 Express.

What may be the cause for this?

For some reason I think this is not good for my computer hard drive. 
I'm considering a format to fix it.

Comment: Which update is Windows trying to install?

Comment: @TeXHeX it's not a specific one, but all started after that I install Visual Web Developer.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling VS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start Windows 7 with the Windows installation media, and then use the Repair feature

Comment: I tried this last night but it doesn't work @Nifle.

Comment: @ValterHenrique tried to `sfc /scannow` as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try this *Fix It* from Microsoft:

[Fix the problem with Microsoft Windows Update that is not working](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/windows_update/en-us)

Answer (score -3):

```
Start->control Panel->Windows Update(in Large icons)->Change Settings->Never Check for Updates
```

Also uncheck
Give me recommended updates...............

**EDIT**
You can do this way
Here’s how I found and deleted the download. I found that all the Windows updates are downloaded to

```
C:\WINDOWS and/or
C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution
```

or C:\WINDOWS\SoftwareDistribution\Download   Mine was in the Download folder and I just opened up the folders until I saw ‘powerpoint’. I knew (by searching the Microsoft KB (knowledge base), that this update came out in July, 2008, so I was pretty certain that was the right one. I deleted it and the folder it came in. Now there are no more notifications!

Comment: This is not likely to help if this is an upate that has downloaded and is trying to install and failing.

Comment: I agree with @DaveM, I would not like to update anymore, because, updates are important to keep the system safe, but only fix this problem.